# How does the microphone seperate whether the sound is coming from the user or the device. Android - Ios

Tags: android, ios, flutter, react-native, mobile-application

In Android and Iod mobile applications, when the user activates the device speaker during a voice or video call, the sound coming from the speaker is not detected by the microphone. In other words, the microphone distinguishes whether the sound is coming from the user or the device.

There are several solutions for Android, such as echo cancellation, Pcm signals, audio signal processing, getMaxAmplitude method.

But these methods are not a general solution, is there a method you can recommend to separate the sound coming into the microphone?